# Adding ' ' around all values in hash

Tags: string, perl

Im trying to surround all values in my hash with single quotes. here is my code.

```
    foreach(values(%properties_hash))
    {
            print "'".$_."'\n";
    }
```

Right now I'm printing. How would I actually augment the value. Also this prints

```
'logs
'format/systemout-2010-format.txt
'analyze
```

It is only 
printing the first '. Why would that be?

Thanks!

Comment: btw, have you considered what would happen if one of the values contained a `'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is working.

```
my %h = (
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3,
        'd' => 4,
);

foreach(values(%h)) {
        print "'".$_."'\n";
}
```

prints

```
'3'
'1'
'2'
'4'
```

Your strings are probably ended with "\r", so the ending "'" is printed over 1 st "'" and therefore don't see the last apostrophe. try:

```
foreach(values(%h)) {
        s/[\r\n]//g;
        print "'".$_."'\n";
}
```

Comment: I agree with your analysis (+1), but it would be better if the problem was fixed at the source (i.e. before even being put in the hash).

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
foreach (keys %properties_hash) {
  $properties_hash{$_} = "'$properties_hash{$_}'\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (values %properties_hash) {
    $_ = "'$_'";
}
```

but why do you want to do this?

Note that this won't yield properly-quoted strings if any of the values have apostrophes in them.

As for your missing quote, maybe those strings have carriage returns in them and the second quote is overwriting the first?